# find port number of IBM MQ Queue Manager

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

I have created a queue manager using
these commands in a linux machine

```
crtmqm MQ1
strmqm MQ1
runmqsc MQ1
```

the queue manager is created successfully,

i wanted to know on which port is the queue manager MQ1 running, i tried all possible ways `netstat -au` and also `ps -ef` command. It looks like it is running on a different port. I am unable to find the correct port number where it is running, could anyone help?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: If either answer provided helped you resolve your question then please click the check mark to the left of the answer that best helped you to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use netstat as root with -p option

```
sudo netstat -nltp
[sudo] password for root: 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1362/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1580/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1480/cupsd
```

The last column gives the PID and 'Program name'. If you are running the queue manager with your user, you don't need to sudo.

Answer (score 5):

By default a new IBM MQ queue manager will not have a listener running on any port.

There is one default `LISTENER` object on a new queue manager which looks like this:

```
$echo "dis listener(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP)"|runmqsc MQ1
....
     1 : dis listener(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP)
AMQ8630: Display listener information details.
   LISTENER(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP)   CONTROL(MANUAL)
   TRPTYPE(TCP)                            PORT(0)
   IPADDR( )                               BACKLOG(0)
   DESCR( )                                ALTDATE(yyyy-mm-dd)
   ALTTIME(hh.mm.ss)
```

If you were to start this `LISTENER` the `PORT(0)` means to start on the default port which is `1414`.

Best practice is to not use SYSTEM objects and create a new object such as:

```
DEFINE LISTENER(LISTENER.1414.TCP) TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(1414) CONTROL(QMGR)
```

The `CONTROL(QMGR)` tells the queue manager to start the listener when the queue manager is started and stop it when the queue manager is ended.

You can manually start and stop the above listener with the commands:

```
START LISTENER(LISTENER.1414.TCP)
STOP  LISTENER(LISTENER.1414.TCP)
```